# iOS Xcode Custom Keyboard Extension advanceToNextInputMode() Not Working in UITabViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard

I am using a UITabControllerView via Storyboard in a Custom Keyboard App Extension with Swift.  There are no exceptions when I debug and I am unable to switch to the next keyboard calling  advanceToNextInputMode().  Here is the structure.

I attempted adding the  advanceToNextInputMode() call to the didAppear function then created a UIbutton. Neither works.

Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the identity inspector of the tabBarItem that i use to switch keyboards I had it set to UIViewController. After switching to UIInputViewController it worked fine.